# NSManagedObject's KVO method calls for external binary data attributes make table view scrolling sluggish, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

After weeks of debugging, I finally found the culprits of the sporadic lags during my table view scrolling. They are `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` calls for an external binary data attribute.

For convenience, you can think of my app as a Twitter client. So the major entity is `Tweet` which has a `thumbnail_pic_data` attribute that I set to `allowsExternalBinaryDataStorage`. A corresponding non-persistent property called `thumbnail_picture` is used as its convenient accessor.

The table view is a tweet list view — the timeline, with every tweet's `thumbnail_picture` displayed inline of its corresponding cell. Pictures are downloaded lazily. After successful downloading, I set `thumbnail_pic_data` with a custom setter as below:

```
- (void)setThumbnail_pic_data:(NSData *)thumbnail_pic_data {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"thumbnail_pic_data"]; // culprit
    [self setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data:thumbnail_pic_data];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"thumbnail_pic_data"]; // culprit

    UIImage *picture;
    if (thumbnail_pic_data) {
        picture = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnail_pic_data];
    }
    self.thumbnail_picture = picture;
}
```

With the code above, I see sporadic lags during my table view scrolling after each picture downloading. After I comment out `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` calls, the lags are gone. So I know they are the culprits.

However, the timing results I got with the follow code shows that they are not *directly* using the CPU for a long time:

```
CFAbsoluteTime t1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"thumbnail_pic_data"];
CFAbsoluteTime t2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"willChangeValueForKey time: %f", t2 - t1);
[self setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data:thumbnail_pic_data];
CFAbsoluteTime t3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data time: %f", t3 - t2);
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"thumbnail_pic_data"];
CFAbsoluteTime t4 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"didChangeValueForKey time: %f", t4 - t3);
```

Timing results:

> willChangeValueForKey time: 0.000145
> setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data time: 0.001512
> didChangeValueForKey time: 0.001810
>
> willChangeValueForKey time: 0.000138
> setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data time: 0.001418
> didChangeValueForKey time: 0.002211
>
> willChangeValueForKey time: 0.000302
> setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data time: 0.001891
> didChangeValueForKey time: 0.003349
>
> willChangeValueForKey time: 0.000162
> setPrimitiveThumbnail_pic_data time: 0.001462
> didChangeValueForKey time: 0.002114

As a temporary workaround, I'll leave those two KVO calls commented out. I'm not sure whether any bad thing would happen for `Core Data Programming Guide` says:

> You must ensure that you invoke the relevant access and change notification methods (willAccessValueForKey:, didAccessValueForKey:, willChangeValueForKey:, didChangeValueForKey:, willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:, and didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:).

Most importantly, I want to know why those two KVO calls makes table view scrolling sluggish  so that hopefully I can find a better workaround.

Comment: Sluggish behaviour means that CPU intensive process are running in the main thread. What if `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` are creating processes in the current (main) thread and that's why you're getting those results? Have you tried running setThumbnail_pic_data: in a background thread?

Comment: @rvil but Core Data is not thread safe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found it.

`-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` will cause `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods to be called which are quite time-consuming collectively if they are called frequently during scrolling in my case. Omitting these two KVO calls spares me those unnecessary `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method calls, but I should not because Apple doc explicitly tells us not to and I do see bad things happen if I do.

Essentially, this problem asks for the same solution of [How to know which property is changed for NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869520/how-to-know-which-property-is-changed-for-nsfetchedresultschangeupdate)

Comment: With all due respect, this is a force workaround, not a solution, and goes against the core data documentation.

Comment: @J2theC yes, I'm not saying it is the solution, I'm just saying it is the cause. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I read your other question too. So when your controller responds to the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method, what in particular about its response when the thumbnail data has changed is so much more costly than its response to other changes?

Comment: @CarlVeazey thumbnail changes are much more frequent than other changes.

Comment: So you say the calls from your fetched results controller are unnecessary, what are you using to refresh the display of your thumbnail images then?

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a different approach, and instead of saving the data/image as the transient property, save as the transient property the name of the image. The NSData object of the image appears of no use to you, so, dont waste memory keeping it since it seems that the only thing you need the content for is to generate the image, and instead create the NSImage object with the NSData from the web, and assign it to a NSCache value with the name of the image (the transient property of your NSManagedObject object) as the key of the image's object.

Comment: NSCache does not persist through sessions, does it?

Comment: No. And you can flush when memory becomes constrained.

Comment: But I need persistent storage.

Comment: Ok. Use your existing image's data property on your entity, create the  UIImage object, store it on the NSCache object. When you try to get the data out of the NSCache object, verify that it actually exists. If it does not, create a new UIImage object and store it on the cache. If memory becomes constrained, the cache will be flushed.  Another thing: are you saving the image's data (when loading lazily) inside the main thread?

Comment: First of all, I'm already using NSCache for UIImage. Secondly, Core Data is not thread safe so I have to call setThumbnail_pic_data on main thread.

Comment: You are having redundant data if you have an NSData of the image, and the UIImage of the image as a property of your entity (even if it is transient). So, you have a copy of the image being represented by an NSData, another copy as a UIImage, and another copy on your NSCache? Eliminate the UIImage property from your entity and just keep the UIImage on the NSCache. Once the cache gets purged, just create the image again using the NSData.

Comment: Second thing: you can save your data on a separate thread. Of course, you can't use a NSManagedObject on different threads. You can't use a NSManagedObjectContext on different threads, but you can have a context on a different thread, save the image, and merge the changes from the background thread with the main thread.

Comment: No redundancy. NSCache for decoded image and NSData for persistent storage.

Comment: but you do have a non-persistent retained property called thumbnail_picture, which is an UIImage.

Comment: if you call the NSManagedObjectContext save method after setting the image with the setThumbnail_pic_data: setter, try assigning the image and saving on a different thread by creating a NSManagedObjectContext on that thread and merging the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification with the main thread's context.

Comment: Actually, no. `thumbnail_picture` is just an interface. Whatever, it has nothing to do with my problem here because even if I never set `thumbnail_picture` the lags are still there due to those KVO calls on  `thumbnail_pic_data`.

Comment: That "interface" is called a property, which seems to be of a retained type considering the fact that [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnail_pic_data]; returns an autoreleased object, unless you are playing with fire and assigning an autoreleasable object to a weak property. Therefore, you are keeping that object in memory on that property and on the NSCache.

Comment: The KVO calls are used by core data to notify the context of changes with the data of its managed object. See the documentation you quoted on your OP. You **must** call those methods.

Comment: I told I just use `thumbnail_picture` as an interface, not a real retained ivar… I know I *should* call KVO calls — that's exactly what I'm concerned in the question — but they are causing severe lags and I can't find other workaround than omitting them. So what's your point about how to solve my *real* problem?

Comment: If it's not a retained var/property, why are you assigning an autoreleased value to it? What type of property is it declared as (weak, strong, retain, assign)? If this is not a retained ivar, what you have is just a memory crash waiting to happen at the return of the runloop, because this memory will be gone by the time you access it again. And if you do not access this value, ever, then what is the point on having this property/ivar/bug/howeveryouwanttocallit?. About the original question: Have you tried saving the image on a secondary thread like I mentioned on a previous comment?